# Retrieve time and sales data using ib_insync (including buying/selling transactions)

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ib-insync

I want to get all the recent data (past 15 most recent transactions) from the time and sales table in IBKR using the ib_insync library. **The problem is** I can't get the most recent data while also getting the information if the past traders were transactions to buy or to sell. **I've tried this:**

```py
endDateTime = datetime.datetime.now()
startDateTime = endDateTime - datetime.timedelta(seconds=15)
time_and_sales_data = self.ib.reqHistoricalTicks(self.STOCK_CONTRACT, numberOfTicks=15, whatToShow='TRADES', useRth=False, startDateTime=startDateTime, endDateTime=endDateTime)

data = util.df(time_and_sales_data)
print(data)
```

This is the output:

```
                        time                                     tickAttribLast     price   size  exchange specialConditions
0  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00  TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=False)  118.8400  100.0    ISLAND
1  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400   55.0    ISLAND                 I
2  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400   13.0      BATS                 I
3  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400   78.0  DRCTEDGE                 I
4  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400   24.0  DRCTEDGE                 I
5  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400   50.0      MEMX                 I
6  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400   23.0     PEARL               F I
7  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400   78.0  DRCTEDGE                 I
8  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400    1.0      BATS               F I
9  2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400   86.0      BATS                 I
10 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00  TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=False)  118.8400  147.0  DRCTEDGE               F
11 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400    1.0      BATS                 I
12 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400    3.0  DRCTEDGE                 I
13 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400    7.0     EDGEA                 I
14 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400    7.0       BYX                 I
15 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400   93.0     EDGEA               F I
16 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00  TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=False)  118.8350  100.0     FINRA
17 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00  TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=False)  118.8300  100.0    ISLAND
18 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400    7.0      MEMX                 I
19 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8400    7.0      MEMX                 I
20 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300   67.0  DRCTEDGE                 I
21 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300    5.0  DRCTEDGE                 I
22 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300   40.0  DRCTEDGE                 I
23 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300    7.0    ISLAND               F I
24 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300   53.0      MEMX                 I
25 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300    6.0    ISLAND                 I
26 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300   48.0    ISLAND                 I
27 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300   52.0    ISLAND                 I
28 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300    6.0  DRCTEDGE               F I
29 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8599    1.0     FINRA                 I
30 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8350    6.0     FINRA                 I
31 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300    1.0    ISLAND                 I
32 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8300    9.0    ISLAND                 I
33 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00  TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=False)  118.8201  200.0     FINRA
34 2023-10-26 16:27:12+00:00   TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True)  118.8200   10.0     FINRA                 I
```

**The problem with this is** that *the data is delayed by a couple of seconds* (at least 9, which is way too much) and *I can't see if the transactions were to buy or to sell*.

**I've then tried this:**

```py
def process_time_and_sales_data_event(msg) -> None:
        print(msg)

self.ib.reqMktData(contract=self.STOCK_CONTRACT, genericTickList="233")
self.ib.pendingTickersEvent += process_time_and_sales_data_event
self.ib.sleep(1)
```

This is the output:

```
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 983990, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 984988, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, lastExchange='P', bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, last=118.97, lastSize=100.0, lastExchange='P', ticks=[TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=4, price=118.97, size=100.0), TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=5, price=118.97, size=100.0)], bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, last=118.97, lastSize=100.0, lastExchange='P', volume=373991.0, high=121.64, low=118.35, close=121.39, ticks=[TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=8, price=-1.0, size=373991.0), TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=6, price=121.64, size=0.0), TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=7, price=118.35, size=0.0), TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=9, price=121.39, size=0.0)], bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, last=118.97, lastSize=100.0, lastExchange='P', volume=373991.0, open=120.56, high=121.64, low=118.35, close=121.39, ticks=[TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 986980, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=14, price=120.56, size=0.0)], bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 987961, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, bid=118.95, bidSize=1800.0, bidExchange='JKPQVNUH', ask=118.97, askSize=900.0, askExchange='PQVNUH', last=118.97, lastSize=100.0, lastExchange='P', volume=373991.0, open=120.56, high=121.64, low=118.35, close=121.39, ticks=[TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 987961, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=1, price=118.95, size=1800.0), TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 987961, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=2, price=118.97, size=900.0)], bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 129873, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, bid=118.95, bidSize=1800.0, bidExchange='JKPQVNUH', ask=118.97, askSize=900.0, askExchange='PQVNUH', last=118.97, lastSize=100.0, lastExchange='P', volume=373991.0, open=120.56, high=121.64, low=118.35, close=121.39, bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 130892, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, bid=118.95, bidSize=1800.0, bidExchange='JKPQVNUH', ask=118.97, askSize=900.0, askExchange='PQVNUH', last=118.97, lastSize=100.0, lastExchange='K', volume=373991.0, open=120.56, high=121.64, low=118.35, close=121.39, bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 131470, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, bid=118.96, bidSize=100.0, bidExchange='H', ask=118.97, askSize=500.0, askExchange='PQVN', last=118.96, lastSize=100.0, lastExchange='K', prevBid=118.95, prevBidSize=1800.0, prevAskSize=900.0, prevLast=118.97, volume=373992.0, open=120.56, high=121.64, low=118.35, close=121.39, ticks=[TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 131470, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=4, price=118.96, size=100.0), TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 131470, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=8, price=-1.0, size=373992.0), TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 131470, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=1, price=118.96, size=100.0), TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 131470, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=3, price=118.97, size=500.0)], bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 271049, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, bid=118.96, bidSize=200.0, bidExchange='QH', ask=118.97, askSize=200.0, askExchange='P', last=118.96, lastSize=100.0, lastExchange='K', prevBid=118.95, prevBidSize=100.0, prevAskSize=500.0, prevLast=118.97, volume=373992.0, open=120.56, high=121.64, low=118.35, close=121.39, ticks=[TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 271049, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=0, price=118.96, size=200.0), TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 271049, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=3, price=118.97, size=200.0)], bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
{Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 733911, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), minTick=0.01, bid=118.96, bidSize=200.0, bidExchange='QH', ask=118.97, askSize=200.0, askExchange='P', last=118.96, lastSize=11.0, lastExchange='K', prevBid=118.95, prevBidSize=100.0, prevAskSize=500.0, prevLast=118.96, prevLastSize=100.0, volume=373992.0, open=120.56, high=121.64, low=118.35, close=121.39, vwap=119.79368522, rtVolume=374004.0, rtTime=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 29, 59, 601000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), ticks=[TickData(time=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 26, 16, 30, 0, 733911, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickType=48, price=118.96, size=11.0)], bboExchange='9c0001', snapshotPermissions=3)}
```

**The problem with this is:** I again, don't know how to see if the transactions were to buy or to sell. The good thing is, the data is updated in real time.

**The question is:** How do I get the past 15 transactions made on the time and sales while also knowing if they were transactions to buy or to sell ?